# Edit a portion of an attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, href

I need to change the href of a link so that instead of saying `.com` at the end, it will say `.net`.

```
$('selector').attr('href','http://example.com');
```

This is the code I'm using at the moment, but it just replaces the entire attribute. I only want it to change `.com`.

Can someone fix my code so that it works properly? I know this is very basic but I'm a beginner with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `attr`'s callback function:

```
$('selector').attr('href', function(_, href) {
    return href.replace('.com', '.net');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = $('selector');
a.attr('href', a.attr('href').replace('.com', '.net'));
```